# JavaScript can not call content script JS function

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am developing chrome extension. I loaded JavaScript file successfully but the problem is external JavaScript (which I have loaded) can not call the function of content script files my code is as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.main_list').click(function()
{
    $('.sub_list') .hide();
    $(this) .parent() .children('.sub_list') .slideToggle("normal");
});


$('#click') .click(function()
{
    $('.sub_list') .hide();
    $(this) .parent() .parent() .children('.sub_list').slideToggle("normal");
});


$('#btnnewtask').click(function()
{
    showdialog('http://localhost:51967/task.aspx');
});
$('#linknewtask').click(function()
{
    showdialog('http://localhost:51967/task.aspx');
});
$('#btnnewcall').click(function()
{
    showdialog('http://localhost:51967/call.aspx');
});
$('#linknewcall').click(function()
{
    showdialog("http://localhost:51967/call.aspx");
});
$('#btnnewmeeting').click(function()
{
    showdialog("http://localhost:51967/meeting.aspx");
});
$('#linknewmeeting').click(function()
{
    showdialog("http://localhost:51967/meeting.aspx");
});
});
```

Showdialog() is function in content script. It is as follow

```
function showdialog(url)
{
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
        xmldoc=xhr.responseXML;
        var js=getfile(getjavascript(xmldoc));
        for(i=0;i<js.length;i++)
        {
            loadjscssfile(js[i],"js");
        }
        var css=getfile(getstylesheet(xmldoc))
        for(i=0;i<css.length;i++)
        {
            loadjscssfile(css[i],"css");
        }
document.file.push(
{"url":url,"css":css,"js":js});
document.getElementById("dialogcontainer3").
innerHTML=gethtmldocument(xmldoc);
        document.getElementById("blacklayer").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("dialogcontainer3").style.display=
"inline-block";
        document.getElementById("dialogcontainer2").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("dialogcontainer1").style.display="block";
        }
}
xhr.open("GET",url,true);
xhr.send();
}
```

But it gives error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showdialog is not defined (program):1
(anonymous function) (program):1
b.event.dispatch (program):3
v.handle (program):3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated
>   world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into,
>   but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page.
>   It looks to each content script as if there is no other JavaScript
>   executing on the page it is running on. The same is true in reverse:
>   JavaScript running on the page cannot call any functions or access any
>   variables defined by content scripts.

See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment

I would suggest trying shared DOM to [communicate between the content script and the page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) or [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

An example of code on the page would be:

```
function showDialog(url) {
    window.postMessage({
        type: "FROM_PAGE",
        text: url
    }, "*");
}
```

And in the contentscript:

```
// This function will NOT collide with showDialog of the page:
function showDialog(url) {
    /* ... */
}

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window) { return; }

    // Make sure we're looking at the correct event:
    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
        showDialog(event.data.text);
    }
}, false);
```

I haven't tested the above, so please consider it to be pseudocode. A similar example is available here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication